# Basic attribute type should not be IDao - intellij message

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, intellij-idea

I am receiving the following message in my Entity object ?

> Basic attribute type should not be IDao

Where it is being used like this :

```
@Entity
@Table
public final class MyEnity {

    @Resource(name = "Dao")
    private IDao dao;
```

I know the name is bad, but what is the problem with injecting my Dao(annotated with repository) into my Domain object that is annotated as a hibernate entity ? And IDao is an interface implemented by Dao class ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`IDao` seems to be a processing element getting injected into an entity and you don't intend to persist it. If so, you should mark it as `transient` so that the ORM will ignore it during CRUD operations on the entity.

```
@Resource(name = "Dao")
private transient IDao dao;
```

BTW, I don't see your entity to be [`@Configurable`](http://vikdor.blogspot.in/2012/08/using-configurable-to-inject-resources.html). How do you plan to get `dao` injected into it? The ORM is going to create a new object of type `MyEntity` using the default constrcutor and call the setters to set the values from the database. Your `IDao dao` will not get injected as such an instance is not a spring-managed bean. You have to mark `MyEntity` as `@Configurable` to make it spring managed so that instances created using `new` operator will get the resource injected.

Comment: OK, is there a better way to inject a dao into a domain object ?

Comment: The only way to get resources injected into an object created using `new` operator is `@Configurable` (http://vikdor.blogspot.in/2012/08/using-configurable-to-inject-resources.html) annotation.

Comment: I am getting the impression, maybe mistakingly, that you think this might not be the best idea ? I can't see how else you can use a reposity/dao with a domain object ?

Comment: You would generally get your repository/dao injected in your manager class or servlet/action class. The entity is either created by the user or retrieved from the DB as a result of user action and both these things are initiated by user input that comes to the servlet/action/manager that already has the DAO injected and you would just use that to work with the entity. Only in domain-driven applications, you would have your DAO present in the entity and for such applications, spring provides the @Configurable annotation.

Comment: Yeah previously I have been injecting the dao into my service layer classes (not controllers/servlets though).I have started to attempt to implement domain-driven desgin properly so @configurable is the way go ...

Comment: That's right, you declare your dependencies as transient in the domain object so that they won't interfere with ORM and you would need to annotate the entities with `@Configurable` to get the dependencies injected. I used it in one of my applications (as mentioned in my blog post).